# Calculator rounding too much

Tags: objective-c, calculator

I have this code written for a calculator application for an iPad but I just could not find a way for it to solve numbers in decimal. When I try to solve for example: 4.5 + 0.5, it will give me just 4 for an answer. I know that there is something missing with this.

Thanks for those incoming responses.

Cheers in advance!

```
- (IBAction)equalsPressed {
    self.typingNumber = NO;
    self.secondNumber = [self.calculatorDisplay.text intValue];

    int result = 0;

    if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
        result = self.firstNumber + self.secondNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
        result = self.firstNumber - self.secondNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"*"]) {
        result = self.firstNumber * self.secondNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
        result = self.firstNumber / self.secondNumber;
   }
    self.calculatorDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.d", result];

    self.displayLabel.text = self.calculatorDisplay.text;
}

- (IBAction) clearPressed: (id)sender {
    self.calculatorDisplay.text = @"";
    self.firstNumber = [self.calculatorDisplay.text intValue];
    self.operation = [sender currentTitle];
}

- (IBAction)backspaceButton: (id)sender {
    self.displayLabel.text = [self.displayLabel.text substringToIndex:self.displayLabel.text.length - 1];
}

- (IBAction)decimalPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *currentText = self.displayLabel.text;
    if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
        self.displayLabel.text = [self.displayLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
int result = 0;
```

1. Change `int` to `double`.
2. Change all uses of `intValue` to `doubleValue`.
3. Change the format string from `@"%2.d"` to `@"%2.f"`.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared result to be an integer on this line:

```
int result = 0;
```

This is causing the values to be rounded, in some way. I'd also double check that other values that you use are of the right type too. If the input values are also `int`s you'd be calculating `int(4.5) + int(0.5)` which is `4 + 0` which is just 4.

If you change this to a float or double (depending on your needs) it should work better. Like so:

```
float result = 0;
```

Comment: See @Eric Jablow 's comment for more help on solving that.

Comment: Thank you Sir @Lego Stormtroopr

Comment: If my answer is useful, a vote would be nice and accepting Eric's answer will be helpful for future users to find appropraite solutions.

Comment: I'm still not done with this one. I've tried to change every int declarations and values I have into float/double and still gave same results which is not calculating the decimal values..

Comment: It works fine now Sir @Lego Stormtroopr. My mistake. I just didn't notice something on the codes. Your solution with Sir Eric Jablow we're all right. Thank you. Solved!